# MySQL - displaying two inner joins in separate columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, inner-join

First of all I have this which returns the date of all the football games where

HomeShotsOnTarget(HST) = FullTimeHomeGoals(FTHG)

or

AwayShotsOnTarget(AST) = FullTimeAWayGoals(FTHG)

```
SELECT MatchDate, HomeTeam, AwayTeam 
FROM matches 
WHERE HST=FTHG or AST=FTAG
```

**This displays**

```
MatchDate | HomeTeam | AwayTeam
2003/08/23    17          32
2003/09/13    24          39
```

and so on and so on...

The numbers under HomeTeam and AwayTeam are the TeamCodes which are in another table called clubs which also has the teams real name.

The following matches the TeamCode for the HomeTeam with the RealName in table clubs.

```
SELECT MatchDate, RealName
FROM club T1 
INNER JOIN matches T2 ON T1.TeamCode = T2.HomeTeam
```

This displays

```
MatchDate|  RealName|
2003/08/23  Arsenal
2003/09/13 Blackburn
```

Etc...

So my problem is I can't seem to find a way that displays the RealName Under HomeTeam and AwayTeam instead of the TeamCode. Like this...

```
MatchDate | HomeTeam | AwayTeam
2003/08/23   Arsenal   Aston Villa
2003/09/13   Blackburn  Man Utd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to join the Team-Table two times, try this query:

```
SELECT 
  MatchDate, 
  T1.RealName, 
  T2.RealName 
FROM 
  matches INNER JOIN club T1 ON (matches.HomeTeam = T1.TeamCode)
          INNER JOIN club T2 ON (matches.AwayTeam = T2.TeamCode)
WHERE 
  HST=FTHG OR AST=FTAG
```

Comment: Thank You for your response!
One small question:
When I do 

SELECT MatchDate, HomeTeam, AwayTeam FROM matches WHERE HST=FTHG or AST=FTAG

It Returns 315 Rows and when I do yours it returns 435 rows.
Could this be something to do with the WHERE clause?

Comment: hm thats strange. Are there any duplicates in the TeamCode-column in the club table?

Comment: No there isn't, TeamCode 1 to 72 with no duplicates :/ I thought it was strange aswell

Comment: Never mind! I retyped it and it returns 315! I must of made a typo!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT MatchDate, homeTeam.RealName AS HomeTeam, awayTeam.RealName AS AwayTeam
FROM matches m
INNER JOIN club homeTeam ON (m.HomeTeam = homeTeam.TeamCode)
INNER JOIN club awayTeam ON (m.AwayTeam = awayTeam.TeamCode);
```

I use to put some meaning labels instead of just, `T1` and `T2`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do another join to the club table for the Away Team, like this:

```
SELECT MatchDate, T1.RealName AS HomeTeamName, T3.RealName AS AwayTeamName 
FROM club T1 
INNER JOIN matches T2 ON T1.TeamCode = T2.HomeTeam 
INNER JOIN club T3 ON T3.TeamCode = T2.AwayTeam
```